SQL Crosstab not showing correct counts
I am trying to create a crosstab that gives me a count of crash type by injury severity, and the data is in three tables (crashes, occupants & pedestrians). The occupants & pedestrians tables have a many-to-one relationship with crashes since there is typically more than one person involved in a crash. I made a view to handle assigning the crash severity to each crash_id based on the occupants and pedestrians tables. Now when I run the query below, the total count is correct, but the counts in each category are not always correct.
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
    'SELECT CONCAT(ct.crash_type_code, '' - '', ct.crash_type_desc) AS crash_type, 
            cs.crash_severity, 
            COALESCE(count(cs.crash_severity), 0) AS count 
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT crash_type_code, crash_type_desc FROM crash_type_lookup
    ) ct
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT crash_severity FROM crash_severity
    ) cs
    LEFT JOIN crash_severity ON cs.crash_severity = crash_severity.crash_severity
                              AND crash_severity.crash_type = ct.crash_type_code
    GROUP BY ct.crash_type_code, ct.crash_type_desc, cs.crash_severity
    ORDER BY 1,2'
)
AS CrashType(crash_type text,
            "01 - Fatal Injury" bigint,
            "02 - Suspected Serious Injury" bigint,
            "03 - Suspected Minor Injury" bigint,
            "04 - Possible Injury" bigint,
            "Property Damage Only" bigint);

Will return this:



crash_type
01 - Fatal Injury
02 - Suspected Serious Injury
03 - Suspected Minor Injury
04 - Possible Injury
Property Damage Only




00 - Unknown
1
1
24




01 - Same Direction (Rear End)
9
40
534
2784
10678


02 - Same Direction (Side Swipe)
5
12
137
525
5725


03 - Right Angle
10
41
540
1785
4825


04 - Opposite Direction (Head On, Angular)
8
19
131
322
645


05 - Opposite Direction (Side Swipe)
3
3
30
60
474


06 - Struck Parked Vehicle
4
20
115
263
5763


07 - Left Turn/U Turn
5
7
125
249
686


08 - Backing
6
46
1559




09 - Encroachment
12
17
154




10 - Overturned
2
8
87
62
86


11 - Fixed Object
33
95
585
880
4810


12 - Animal
36
57
2247




13 - Pedestrian
55
46
205
292
92


14 - Pedacyclist
6
17
121
108
52


15 - Non-Fixed Object
1
5
20
18
511


16 - Railcar - Vehicle
2






99 - Other
2
3
36
20
288



But row 1, the 00 - Unknown category, should be null for the first two columns (Fatal Injury and Suspected Serious Injury) and 1, 1, 24 for the last three columns. So it seems it's just not accounting for the fact that the first two columns are null, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Here is a sample of the data showing how the 00 - Unknown crash types should be distributed.
mercer_crashes=# SELECT c.crash_id, crash_type_code, crash_severity FROM crashes c LEFT JOIN crash_severity cs ON c.crash_id = cs.crash_id WHERE crash_type_code = '00';



crash_id
crash_type_code
crash_severity




2019110319-29497
00
03 - Suspected Minor Injury


2017111117-004544
00
04 - Possible Injury


2017110317-36014
00
Property Damage Only


2017110717-38624-AC
00
Property Damage Only


2017111117-006380
00
Property Damage Only


2017111117-006610
00
Property Damage Only


2017111117001399
00
Property Damage Only


2017111117001803
00
Property Damage Only


2017111417-19645
00
Property Damage Only


2017111417-25979
00
Property Damage Only


201811022018-01727
00
Property Damage Only


2018110318-28221
00
Property Damage Only


2018111118004932
00
Property Damage Only


2018111118004944
00
Property Damage Only


2018111118012298
00
Property Damage Only


2018111118014205
00
Property Damage Only


2018111418-17386
00
Property Damage Only


2020110120-9355
00
Property Damage Only


2020110320-25261
00
Property Damage Only


2020110320-30145
00
Property Damage Only


2020111120003327
00
Property Damage Only


2020111120003940
00
Property Damage Only


2020111420-24013
00
Property Damage Only


2021110321-078180
00
Property Damage Only


2021111121006276
00
Property Damage Only


2021111421-13746
00
Property Damage Only



Other areas are probably incorrect also, I haven't checked everything since its obvious it's not working right. Any help would be much appreciated.
Here is a sample of the crash_severity view:



crash_id
crash_severity




2017110114-360
Property Damage Only


2017110117-10026
Property Damage Only


2017110117-10075
Property Damage Only


2017110117-10209
04 - Possible Injury


2017110117-1022
Property Damage Only


2017110117-10231
Property Damage Only


2017110117-10253
03 - Suspected Minor Injury


2017110117-10266
Property Damage Only


2017110117-1029
04 - Possible Injury


2017110117-10318
Property Damage Only


2017110117-10329
03 - Suspected Minor Injury


2017110117-10363
Property Damage Only


2017110117-10386
Property Damage Only


2017110117-10392
04 - Possible Injury


2017110117-1040
Property Damage Only


2017110117-10451
04 - Possible Injury


2017110117-10462
Property Damage Only


2017110117-10507
Property Damage Only


2017110117-10545
Property Damage Only


2017110117-10632
Property Damage Only


2017110117-1067
04 - Possible Injury


2017110117-10678
Property Damage Only


2017110117-10714
Property Damage Only


2017110117-10715
Property Damage Only


2017110117-10717
04 - Possible Injury


2017110117-10756
Property Damage Only




Hi - please update your question with sample data for your source tables and the result you want to achieve, all as editable text formatted as tables. Please don’t use images as no one can copy your data/code

@NickW I updated the question, let me know if you need any other info!


it seems it's just not accounting for the fact that the first two columns are null

Yes, it is not.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

You COUNT the data from dimension. They are always non-null. You should COUNT the facts.
This should work correctly:
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
    'SELECT CONCAT(ct.crash_type_code, '' - '', ct.crash_type_desc) AS crash_type, 
            cs.crash_severity, 
            COALESCE(count(crash_severity.crash_severity), 0) AS count 
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT crash_type_code, crash_type_desc FROM crash_type_lookup
    ) ct
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT crash_severity FROM crash_severity
    ) cs
    LEFT JOIN crash_severity ON cs.crash_severity = crash_severity.crash_severity
                              AND crash_severity.crash_type = ct.crash_type_code
    GROUP BY ct.crash_type_code, ct.crash_type_desc, cs.crash_severity
    ORDER BY 1,2'
)
AS CrashType(crash_type text,
            "01 - Fatal Injury" bigint,
            "02 - Suspected Serious Injury" bigint,
            "03 - Suspected Minor Injury" bigint,
            "04 - Possible Injury" bigint,
            "Property Damage Only" bigint);

